# Minimizing a graph with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

Suppose we have a directed graph defined as following:

```
 node | neighbor
 -----------------
   1  | 2
   1  | 3
   2  | 4
   2  | 3
   3  | 4
```

the above table defines the only the edges between two nodes, a couple `(1,2)`for example means that node `1` and `2` are connected by an edge, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkgJA.png) is a plot of the graph.

I also have a table of the transitive closure of the graph, this table holds all the possible paths of the graph (for example: `(1,3)` is present twice because it can be reached either directly or by the path `1=>2=>3`), here is the table:

```
 node | neighbor
 -----------------
   1  | 2
   1  | 3
   2  | 4
   2  | 3
   3  | 4
   1  | 3
   1  | 4
   1  | 4
   2  | 4
```

from these two tables, I want to return a minimized graph without losing any reachability, an idea was to only return edges that are not in dependency of the two tables, here's an example: 
`(1,2)` is in the first table and `(2,3)` is in the second, and therefore `(1,3)` can be deleted from the first table because you can reach node `3` from `1` passing by node `2` 
the outuput table should look like this then:

```
 node | neighbor
 -----------------
   1  | 2
   2  | 3
   3  | 4
```

How can I write an SQL query that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select node, neighbor, 1 is_initial from graph
    union all 
    select c.node, g.neighbor, 0
    from cte c
    inner join graph g on g.node = c.neighbor
)
select node, neighbor
from graph g
where not exists (
        select 1 
        from cte c
        where c.node = g.node and c.neighbor = g.neighbor and c.is_initial = 0
    )
order by node, neighbor
```

This uses the first table only (I called it `graph`). We start by generating all possible paths with a recursive query. This is quite similar to your closure table, but with one extra column, `is_initial`, that indicates whether the path comes from the original table, or was generated during a further iteration.

Then, all that is left to do is filter the graph to remove tuples that match a "non-initial" path.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0888dd791e6b1330ddf490af5a929bc4)**:

```
node | neighbor
---: | -------:
   1 |        2
   2 |        3
   3 |        4
```